# Finding the maximum absolute error

Tags: numerical-methods, self-learning, error-propagation

Given, $c=15300 \pm 100$. Then what is the maximum absolute error in $c^3$?

**My attempt:**

Let $u = c^3$, then maximum absolute error in $u$ is $\Delta u = \frac{du}{dc}\times \Delta c = 3c^2\times \Delta c = 3\times 15300^2 \times 100 = 70.23\times 10^9$.

I want to know if my attempt is correct because my textbook gives completely different answer, $5.766\times 10^{12}$.

Please anyone help me clear this doubt. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's weird. I think the error cannot be larger than $1.405\times 10^{11}$ because
$$
(15~300 + 100)^3 - (15~300-100)^3 \approx 1.405 \times 10^{11}
$$

Comment: You used $1500$ instead of $15300$ and $70.23\times 10^{9}$ is correct.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Ok, I have edited it now.

Comment: @MattiP. So...am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you mention is a linear approximation of the error, so it does not provide an exact bound. Also, when applying the formula, you are assuming that $c=15300$, which is not the case. What you could say using that formula is that

$$
|\Delta u| \approx |f'(c) \Delta c| \leq 3c^2 |\Delta c| \leq 3(15300+100)^2 \cdot 200 \approx 1.42 \times 10^{11}
$$

However, as it was pointed out, since $c \in [15200, 15400]$, surely $c^3 \in [ 15200^3, 15400^3]$ ando so, if you approximate $c^3$ by $15300^3$, the maximum absolute error is approx. $7.07 \times 10^{10}$.